# Regexp for current numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

Hi I need to restrict input only for correct numbers from -9999 to 9999 using regexps in JS. So that the user CAN'T input numbers like:

```
9-985
02564
1234-
```

Thanks.

Comment: Any reason this has to be done with a regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This regex should work:

```
^-?\d{1,4}$
```

This does not allow empty string - it can be a number from -9999 to 9999, including 0.

Comment: This is going to let one of your "not-allowed" cases through , specifically `02564`.

Comment: @paxdiablo: this regex will not pass `02564`. It will pass `0256`, but that still counts as number from -9999 to 9999.

Answer (score 3):

```
^-?\d{1,4}$
```

This expression optionally starts with a `-` and is 1 to 4 digits only.

Comment: Actually `{,4}` quantifier isn't supported in JS `'1'.match(/\d{,4}/)` -> `null`

Comment: Shouldn't be at least one digit?